# LinearLayout not aligning properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have an social media icon and the username to its right.  I have this linearlayout vertically throughout my screen, so I want the end of the icons and the start of their usernames to line up in the center.  So here's what I did:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/youtubeSection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/youtubeIcon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/youtube_circle_64" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/youtubeTV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="youtube_handle" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I dont get why the social media icon is still centered to it's weight(a quarter of the way to the width of the screen).  The imageview should take half the width, then right align the icon it contains, thus doing what I described earlier.

Comment: is it applicable for you to use compoundDrawable for TextView..?

Comment: Try setting `android:layout_width="0dp"` for both views. The `layout_weight` will then expand each of them to half the available width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a `RelativeLayoutt` to achieve this effect:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/youtubeSection"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/youtubeIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/youtube_circle_64"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/youtubeTV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="youtube_handle" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Another option is to set the left drawable on the `TextView` (which has the added advantage of removing a lot of the layouts complexity):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/youtubeTV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/youtube_circle_64"
    android:text="youtube_handle" />
```

Comment: dumbfounded as to why my solution wasn't moving the icon but your way works.